# MvvmCross private variable not changing value

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MVVMCross with Xamarin to develop an Android app. I have a private variable _currentCommand that is not being modified within a property as I would expect.
I have this ViewModel:

```
public class FooNavigationViewModel : MvxViewModel {
    public FooNavigationViewModel () {
        _viewModels.Add (new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<DatePickerViewModel> ()));
        _viewModels.Add (new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<FooReasonViewModel> ()));
        _viewModels.Add (new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<FooBleedListViewModel> ()));
    }

    private List<MvxCommand> _viewModels = new List<MvxCommand> ();
    private MvxCommand _currentCommand;
    public MvxCommand NextCommand {
        get {
            int nextViewId = _currentCommand == null ? 1 : _viewModels.IndexOf (_currentCommand) + 1;
            if (nextViewId >= _viewModels.Count) {
                return new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<FooSummaryViewModel> ());
            } else {
                _currentCommand = _viewModels [nextViewId];
                return _currentCommand;
            }
        }
    }

    public MvxCommand CancelCommand {
        get {
            return _currentCommand;
                //new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<MainMenuViewModel> ());
        }
    }

    public MvxCommand PreviousCommand {
        get {
            int nextViewId = _currentCommand == null ? 0 : _viewModels.IndexOf (_currentCommand) - 1;
            if (nextViewId < 0) {
                return new MvxCommand (() => ShowViewModel<MainMenuViewModel> ());
            } else {
                _currentCommand = _viewModels [nextViewId];
                return _currentCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hooked up to these navigation controls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/foo"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="Previous"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
        local:MvxBind="Click PreviousCommand" />
    <Button
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        local:MvxBind="Click CancelCommand" />
    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        local:MvxBind="Click NextCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The navigation is in a fragment, and it is used to switch other fragments out of a framelayout. Switching fragments works fine, but it only advances a single fragment, no matter how many times the button is clicked.

My assumption would be if I load the view and click the Cancel button, null would be returned. However, the DatePickerViewModel is returned. In fact, no matter what I click, the DatePickerViewModel is always returned from CancelCommand. However, if I click NextCommand, FooReasonViewModel is returned as expected. I'm very confused about how _currentCommand can have no setters and be private (so should only be able to be modified within my FooNavigationViewModel), and be returned with one value, then immediately have a different value. I assume something weird is happening with reflection and MVVMCross, but really have no idea. All I want to do is have a view model that lets me step forward and backwards between views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really follow your code, but I think what is happening is nothing to do with reflection but is instead simply about when the Command properties are evaluated:

- when your view is first shown, the bindings are evaluated and the Click events are bound to the ICommand property values
- after that there is never any `RaisePropertyChanged` so the bindings are never reevaluated
- so the Click events stay bound to the original properties.

To change this, you could call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => NextCommand); RaisePropertyChanged(() => PreviousCommand);` whenever the `nextViewId` changes

Alternatively, you could change your commands so that the logic occurs within their `Action` - e.g. something like:

```
 public MvxCommand NextCommand {
    get {
         // this return is executed when the binding happens
         return new MvxCommand(() => {
             // this switch is executed when the Click happens
             switch(nextViewId) {
                case 0:
                  // ...
                case 1:
                  // ...
           }
         });
    }
}
```